# NavigationItem titleView being cleared when new view pushed onto navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uinavigationitem

Why navigation item `titleview` is cleared every time I push a new view onto the view stack via the navigation controller. Why does this happen? In my first view controller I have set a `UIImageView` with a `titleview` manually. But when the view is changed the titleview is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

for every separate view controller you should add the title view. that wil be like a navigation controller. u can add an imageview in the top. have some button in the left corner. give this action when you click that button.

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

it will pop your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know Which Code are you using??,

I have tried this code its working,

```
UIImage *Myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"titleBar.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Myimage];
```

Comment: i used the same code, but when view is changed the titleview reference is nil